# Are there any significant differences between reading mangas as compared to watching the animation?

Tags: anime-production

The title says it all.

Personally, I am not fond of reading and when it comes to this, I'd prefer to watch the anime rather than read its manga. However, there are some who prefer reading the manga.

*Why is that so?* Are there any differences or is it just that one is better than the other at times?

Comment: I know some people like my friend think that "Anime" goes too fast and misses some details in the plot.

Comment: This question is opinion-based as the preference of manga over anime may be different depending on people opinion (See [don't ask](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). What's more, anime recommendation is not a part of this website. If you desire recommendations, you can come to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) when you have [enough reputation](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)!

Comment: Alright, thanks! Anyhow, I really thought, if there are some significant differences between the mangas and animated versions of anime. It seems, its only a matter of personal preference and depends that, in which way an anime is made better. 
P.S : Gotta love how everyone is so punctual in their text.

Comment: It can also depend on how the Anime/Manga/Light Novel was made. with Shin Sekai Yori many people complain about the Manga adaptation of the Light Novel because it was more fanservicey than the anime adaption while some people don't like the anime of long running series because of the filler episodes

Comment: Wish this post would be removed off " On Hold " since the question has been altered in-order to perhaps fit in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly subjective, but as someone who enjoys reading manga (even when I'm also watching the anime) I'm sure a number of people have reasons similar to mine:

- For a long runnning series, the manga is usually farther ahead, so you find out what happens next sooner.
- For a long running series, the manga avoids the filler that the anime can sometimes be forced to resort to.
- The manga is the original source material, and the anime adaptations are not always faithful. By reading the manga, you are getting the 'real' story.
- Similarly, some manga run far longer than the anime adaptations (Claymore, for example.) so the manga is the only way you can get the rest of the story.
- Not all manga are given an anime, so by avoiding manga, you may be missing out on a good series.

And of course, there's the obvious one: I enjoy reading.

Comment: This answer is short, to the point and consists of valuable points. Hence, voted as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

While the preference to read the manga over watching the anime may be opinion-based, there lies within that some facts readily understood outside the anime/manga community.

- Some people prefer to read the book *instead* of watching the movie.

  - Perhaps they don't have access to the anime/movie.
  - Perhaps they prefer manga/books as a medium, maybe avoiding their experience of the manga/book being "corrupted" by watching an anime/movie adaptation of it.
  - Perhaps they feel the need to enjoy this hobby in private and they can't watch an anime/movie with adequate privacy.
- Some people prefer to read the book *before* watching the movie.

  - Perhaps they prefer to know the manga/book to educate their anime/movie experience.
  - Perhaps they have greater access to the manga/book than the anime/movie.
  - Perhaps they couldn't wait to read the manga/book before there was an anime/movie adaptation.
- Some people prefer to read the book *after* watching the movie.

  - Perhaps they were unaware of the book/manga before watching the anime/movie.
  - Perhaps they use anime/movie adaptations to educate their selections of manga/books.
    "If they can't make an anime/movie adaptation, is it worth it for me to read the book/manga?"
    "That anime/movie had an interesting concept. I wonder how the book/manga treats it."
  - Perhaps reading is difficult (learning disability, non-native language, *et al.*), so watching an anime/movie adaptation reduces the learning curve and gives them greater access to the manga/book.
- Some people prefer to watch the movie *instead* of reading the book.

  - Perhaps they don't have access to the book/manga.
    "I have trouble reading because I have dyslexia."
    "I'd rather read the manga in Japanese, but it's hard for me to find it."
  - Perhaps they prefer anime/movies as a medium.
  - Perhaps they feel the need to enjoy this hobby in private and they can't read the book/manga (or store it) with adequate privacy.

When the material is in my native language (English), I prefer to read the book before I watch the movie. However, when the material is in a non-native language (Japanese), I prefer to read the manga *after* I watch the anime, using the anime almost like one would Cliff's Notes. But those are *my* preferences and their justifications; they may not be yours or your friends'.

This isn't an exhaustive list of justifications or reasons. Feel free to add to them if you want.

Comment: Deserves an up-vote, but cannot due to insufficient rep points. Thank you for your time answering the question!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of monster musume there are noticible differences between the manga and anime
As is the case of many series so perhaps people watch for the differences